# Usage limits for services when used with Google Maps Javascript API v3

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to clarify the usage limits for Google Maps services (e.g. Places, Directions, etc) when used with the Google Maps Javascript API.

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage)

> The JavaScript Maps API V3 is a free service, available for any web
>   site that is free to consumers

and

> For-profit web sites are permitted to generate up to 25 000 map loads
>   per day using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

Now each Google Maps service API has its own usage limits:

- Places API allows 1,000 or 100,000 (if you're verified) requests per 24
  hours.
- Directions API allows 2,500 requests per day

In my web app I'm using the places library and direction service via the [Javascript API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) Do the usage limits for each service apply when used with the Javascript API? The documentation doesn't make that clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  The usage limit for Google maps APIs affects only when ***your site gets more traffic***.

Each API has its own usage limitation.

- [**Google Geocoding Service:**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits) 2,500 requests per day
- [**Google Maps Javascript API :**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) up to 25,000 map loads per day for each
  service.

  This includes:

  1. a map is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API (V2 or V3) when
     loaded by a web page or application;
  2. a Street View panorama is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API (V2
     or V3) by a web page or application that has not also displayed a
     map;
  3. a SWF that loads the Maps API for Flash is loaded by a web page or
     application; or
  4. a single request is made for a map image from the Static Maps API.
  5. a single request is made for a panorama image from the Street View
     Image API.

If you think that your site exceeds these usage limit, then you should consider to  ***purchase a [Maps API for Business license](http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/)***.

Check the following sites for additional information:

- [**Understanding how the Maps API usage limits affect your
  sites**](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.in/2011/11/understanding-how-maps-api-usage-limits.html)
- **[What usage limits apply to the Maps API?](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usagelimits)**

Hope that the above information helps you.

Comment: We are using JavaScript Maps API for the features like 1) Plotting polygons (like http://173.248.174.144/~bethelipa/dev/plot-area-demo.php) 2) Getting latitude and longitude of a location 3) Finding whether a latitude and longitude is inside the plotted polygon. We understand that 2,500 requests per day is free for lifetime. Please confirm Also do have feature list for free vs paid version

Comment: @SODC you can find the latest pricing here https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

Below are the details about Maps JS API - Billing. I checked with chat support. Hope this helps some one

1. Once we enable billing we will have free 28500 map loads each month ($200 free credits each month). Reference link: https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing
2. If we haven’t enable billing we will not able to use this feature once our free credits are over
3. Once we enable billing we have the possibility for the following
   a)  We can set a limit for our daily usage. Reference link: https://developers.google.com/maps/optimization-guide#consumption_optimization
   b)  We can track our usage
4. One page load will be considered as one map load