# How to use Google Maps without a key? (from static to dynamic with URL)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have seen that many users have asked this question, but in fact there is still no answers with examples of how to use Google Maps without a key (all the answers are references to another webpages).

I have managed to use Google Maps without the key, but I only managed to get a static map. Do you have any idea how do this dynamic?

```
var img = new Image();

img.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-32.0000343,-58.0000343&zoom=5&size=300x300&sensor=true&visualRefresh=true";

return img; //OR document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Even if you simply click this link you can see the map, and if you change the "url properties" you can "edit" the map:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-32.0000343,-58.0000343&zoom=5&size=300x300&sensor=true&visualRefresh=true

When I say "dynamic map" I mean to somethins like this: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/map-simple

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"?  You want a link to a [Google Map](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=lincoln,+NE&hl=en&sll=40.85968,-74.157769&sspn=0.201496,0.304871&hnear=Lincoln,+Lancaster,+Nebraska&t=m&z=12), so you can zoom and pan it?  Like [this](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=-32.0000343,-58.0000343&hl=en&ll=-31.952162,-58.007812&spn=7.230774,9.755859&sll=40.806862,-96.681679&sspn=0.201657,0.304871&t=m&z=5)

Comment: Exactly! Sorry I'll add this to description

Comment: Go to google maps.  Set up the map as you want it to appear.  Click on the "link" icon (looks like a chain).  Copy that URL and use it.  Or for more control, use the Google [Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics)

Comment: Don't use the deprecated [v2 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) (which the example you posted is using).

Comment: I need to change positions according to my application, so I think the API is the right way, but all the examples there are with an api key and I want to do this without a key.

Comment: Since 22 June 2016 you need an API key (http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html) but I have found a workaround to use Google Maps API without key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148097/google-maps-api-without-key/38809129#38809129

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @geocodezip said, You're looking for **Google Maps Javascript v3**.

Here is simple example of using it(picked from my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17616832/1671639)), this doesn't need any keys.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
```

**Javascript:**

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.565529, -80.197645);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

     //=====Initialise Default Marker    
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'marker'
     //=====You can even customize the icons here
    });

     //=====Initialise InfoWindow
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "<B>Skyway Dr</B>"
  });

   //=====Eventlistener for InfoWindow
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have created a [**simple fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/2625/) for your reference.

Hope you got some idea.

Since you're not interested in using keys, [**Beware of the limits**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17872909/1671639).

**Google Maps Javascript API :** up to 25,000 map loads per day for each
   service.

This includes:

1. a map is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API (V2 or V3) when
   loaded by a web page or application;
2. a Street View panorama is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API (V2
   or V3) by a web page or application that has not also displayed a
   map;
3. a SWF that loads the Maps API for Flash is loaded by a web page or
   application; or
4. a single request is made for a map image from the Static Maps API.
5. a single request is made for a panorama image from the Street View
   Image API.

From your comments,

I too tried using `canvas`, it was not working.

```
 var mapCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
```

But this is working good with `div` element.

```
var mapCanvas = document.createElement("div");
mapCanvas.style.width = "200px";
mapCanvas.style.height = "200px";
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vQKkq/8/)

Don't forget to set width and height properties.

Comment: Thanks! I think I forget to write some requirements for what I need but this solve this question so it is the answer (the fiddle is so good)

Comment: @gal007 it is not working with canvas element.  but check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vQKkq/8/.  I have used a `div`.  Hope this is enough.

Comment: The sensor parameter is no longer required for the Google Maps JavaScript API. It won't prevent the Google Maps JavaScript API from working correctly, but we recommend that you remove the sensor parameter from the script element. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#deverrorcodes

Comment: This works fine, but is this answer still valid after google introduced restrictions? will this url work on Production Android and iOS app also, if I use webview inside app and load map?

Comment: this solution work fine on jsfiddle but when i use it on my site it give me an error that says this map cant load because  you need API code, what i have to do?

Answer (score 18):

This has worked for me. I tried it on localhost. Various other solutions in stackoverflow didn't helped.

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo urlencode($address); ?>&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />
```

In this way we can generate maps dynamically based upon the address we entered in the back end.

Comment: this is brilliant

Answer (score 3):

I am putting an example on plunker

http://plnkr.co/T4eULTnKbWCKlABPI4pu

and the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=London&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works fine, but is this answer still valid after google introduced restrictions? will this url work on Production Android and iOS app also, if I use webview inside app and load map with iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics) (lots of [good examples in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/))

Comment: I need to change positions according to my application, so I think the API is the right way, but all the examples there are with an api key and I want to do this without a key.

Comment: An API key is not required for the Google Maps Javascript API v3.  It is recommended and necessary if you want to track your API usage or if you run into the free API limits and want to pay for more.

Answer (score 0):

try it from android phone

```
href = "google.streetview:cbll=51.470305,-0.183842&cbp=1,10,,0,2.0&mz=mapZoom"
```

add this to your anchor link