# Google Api Request Limit exceeded

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api

I am using the google directions api in my php code to check the directions from a location A to a location B. It is showing that I have exceeded my request limit.
I found out that there is 2500 per day limit for the api here. 
[Usage limits for services when used with Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865291/usage-limits-for-services-when-used-with-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)
I would like to know how to get unlimited requests. Do I have to use maps for work?

Comment: Buy the API and pay for it

Comment: @Hudixt would that give me unlimited use?

Comment: There is no "unlimited use".  You can pay for additional requests.

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for the API usage from [here](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and use the API key to access the API. Then the requests above the limits will not be denied but rather they will be billed to your account. You would have to pay the bills periodically. Go through the developers console to gain more information regarding the payments and API usage restrictions.