# Google Map Services(Places) returning error message "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API." But I've used it just for a while

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps service (Places, directions). After using for a while I am receiving response :

`{   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",   "predictions" : [],   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"}.`

I found this link [Usage limits for services when used with Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865291/usage-limits-for-services-when-used-with-google-maps-javascript-api-v3). In this link it is mentioned that "Places API allows 1,000 or 100,000 (if you're verified) requests per 24 hours." But i have not requested it even for 200 times.
Is there some other reason for this response or is there any alternative to get rid of this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing/terms of use and not about coding.

Comment: How are you making the request? Are you using the [Google Maps Javascript API Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) or the [Places web service](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/)?

Comment: Which kind of requests do you send(when you e.g. use a textSearch a single request will count as 10 request against your quota)

Answer (score 1):

### Usage Limits for Google Maps API Web Services

Yes. There is another possible reason for getting the "Over query" message. And it's a common problem.  If you make subsequent query requests too quickly, Google will respond with the over query limit message you posted.

From the [Google API spec](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits)

**Usage limits exceeded**

If you exceed the usage limits you will get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status code as a response.

This means that the web service will stop providing normal responses and switch to returning only status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT until more usage is allowed again.

This can happen:

- **Within a few seconds, if the error was received because your
  application sent too many requests per second.**
- Some time in the next 24 hours, if the error was received because
  your application sent too many requests per day. The time of day at
  which the daily quota for a service is reset varies between customers
  and for each API, and can change over time.

**Add delay between requests to eliminate error**

You need to insert a delay between  requests to the Google Map API to get rid of the message and get the API to respond. How you implement a delay depends upon the platform you're using.